# MigraDoc - extra and unwanted NewLines

Tags: pdf-generation, newline, migradoc

I have a code, where I create a paragraph with 4 lines, 3 of them use tabs to separate row labels and parameter. Astonishingly, a code that worked flawlessly in another form is giving me big headache in current form, even though it is practically 100% identical. Two extra lines appear between line label and a parameter.

```
    Dim ParPara As New Paragraph   ' create new paragraph
    Dim formtext As New FormattedText
    formtext.Bold = True
    formtext.AddText("ABC 12345") 
    Dim formtext2 As New FormattedText
    formtext2.Bold = True
    formtext2.AddText("163658468435831484")   
    Dim formtext3 As New FormattedText
    formtext3.Bold = True
    formtext3.AddText("PARAMETER 1")  
    ParPara.Add(formtext4)
    ParPara.AddLineBreak()     ' intentional line break at the end of line
    ParPara.AddText("Row Header 1:")
    ParPara.AddTab()
    ParPara.Add(formtext)
    ParPara.AddLineBreak()     ' intentional line break at the end of line
    ParPara.AddText("Row Header 2:")
    ParPara.AddTab()
    ParPara.Add(formtext2)
    ParPara.AddLineBreak()     ' intentional line break at the end of line
    ParPara.AddText("Row Header 3:")
    ParPara.AddTab()
    ParPara.Add(formtext3)
    ...
    TableRowHead0F.Cells(1).Add(ParPara)
```

I even compared in-memmory content of the paragraph and it's 100% identical in both forms, one working flawlessly and another one inserting extra NewLine breaks:

[image]

The in-memmory structure is correct:

[image]

The migradoc styles are set identically in both forms (working and failing) too.

Anyone has any ideas why this is happenning?

**EDIT:** As suggested, I compared MDDDLs and I see no differences:
[image]

I don't know, if there can be some context (cell style?) affecting this, but it's really odd. Not the first time I see something like this with MigraDoc...

**EDIT 2:**

The problems was in switching an order of lines of definition of one style, I had 2nd line of this code at the end:

```
    Dim sStyle As Style = PruvDoc.Styles(StyleNames.Normal)
    sStyle = PruvDoc.Styles.AddStyle("Quest", "Normal")
    sStyle.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Clear()
    sStyle.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.AddTabStop("9cm", TabAlignment.Left, TabLeader.Dots)
```

...and that meant that tab stops were applied to the "Normal" style, instead "Quest". Against expectation, it was defined well after the part, where the problems ocured(good to know).

Comment: You can create MDDDL files for the version that works and for the version that does not work and then compare the MDDDL files. See here: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocDDL.ashx - "practically 100% identical" except for some important differences, most likely not showing in your code snippet.

Comment: Of course "some important differences" are possible, though they must be very hidden. I copied the whole code and modified only the variables and when I ran into the problem, I even ran a diff (it's little bit difficult to evaluate perfectly, as the variables differ). When I suspected something could had happen with the variable content, I inserted hard strings (as shown), but problem persist. Anyhow, I'll try to follow your suggestion and use MDDDL. Thank you.

Comment: The MDDDL, focusing on the cell with the affected paragraph, are identical. I added picture to my question.

Comment: It can be something simple like page margins, tab stops, font size, font, font style or or or. Use the IssueSubmissionTemplate from the PDFsharp site to make the issue reproducible.

Comment: I found the problem, as I wrote in Edit 2. If you copy your suggestions into an answer, I'll accept it as a correct way to resolve such issues. Otherwise I'll close it with my own answer later. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Thanks for that fair offer, I posted an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful approach to investigate such problems: You can create MDDDL files for the version that works and for the version that does not work and then compare the MDDDL files.
See here:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocDDL.ashx

MDDDL files are somewhat readable and can be used to check what you actually add to your document - even if you only have a version that does not work as expected.